# I was accompanied by my friends "for" or "to" a picnic

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, usage

> A) I was accompanied by my friends **for** a picnic.
>
> B) I was accompanied by my friends **to** the picnic.

Which of two is correct? Can we use 'for' with the word 'accompanied'>

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link to add to your question the details of your own research on these two prepositions.

Comment: Why not? "accompanied to a place" or "accompanied for a reason". It is matter of understanding prepositions.

Comment: @user3169: The complement of **for**, if it is linked to **accompanied**, must describe the reason for or the occasion of the accompaniment. "The mental patient was accompanied  to his padded cell by orderlies for his own safety." "The President will be accompanied by three security details for the occasion."  If we think of **picnic** as an occasion, then I suppose so.

Comment: Because **accompanied to** is so common a collocation with destinations and venues and activities, usages like *I was accompanied by my friends **for** a concert.* get interfered with and thus sound marginal. Somehow, the definite article lessens that discord for me, "...for *the* concert".

Answer (score 1):

Either one is grammatically correct, but fluent speakers would usually say "to".

"Accompany" means to go with. And you generally "go" "to" somewhere. "To" in this case has the meaning of indicating the destination. So it's common to say "accompany to". Where did we go? We went to a picnic.

But "for" is also valid. "For" in this case indicating the reason or purpose. Why did my friends accompany me? Because we were having a picnic.

Comment: @EllieK I think I would say "to"

Comment: @Jay Accompany does not only mean *go with*.  It can also mean *be with*.  Do I generally *be to* somewhere?  Please bring your full repertoire of English skills when helping learners.  Including definition #2.

Comment: @EllieK Yes, "accompany" can also mean "be with". So yes, it would be valid, as you say, to write "accompany me at the picnic". But when you say "fluent speakers would say" that, I believe that's incorrect. Google Ngrams shows "accompany to" as much more common than "accompany at". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&content=accompany+to%2Caccompany+at&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccompany%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccompany%20at%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

**From Oxford Collocations Dictionary 2nd Ed. VERB + PICNIC** ▪ go for (esp. BrE), go on (esp. AmE)

**From Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's Dictionary** “Are you going to the picnic?” “Probably.”

**From Longman Language Activator 2nd Ed.**
If you don’t come to the picnic you’ll miss out on all the fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can go on/for/to a picnic.

The said prepositions can also be used in case of the verb accompany.  "To"
is more common than "on", and "for" is far less common.